# Laravel Apache DirectoryIndex now needs index.php

Tags: laravel, apache, mod-rewrite, permissions, directoryindex

We have an app that we upgraded from 5.x to 7.x. After a fair amount of edits (really not bad) we have the 7.x version running.

But to get the app's root URL to work we had to add index.php to the DirectoryIndex setting. Without this we got permission denied error (as access to directory not allowed).

paths beneath the url seem to work (ignoring css issues, etc), so we assume the rewrite was working.

Why the change? Doesn't seem like the migration should have changed this.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I see that the original .htaccess file had DirectoryIndex set. Not sure if this was a laravel change or something we added.